# My code works well but when I try to search that already included character, it wasn't matching and keeps saying not found

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

```
from array import *

alphabets = array('u', [])

lettersRange = int(input("Enter how many letters do you want to enter "))
for i in range(lettersRange):
    addLetter = input("Enter Alphabet ")
    alphabets.append(addLetter)

print("alphabets that you've entered are ", alphabets)

for i in range(len(alphabets)):
    print(alphabets[i])

searchLetter = input("enter the letter to search if its is available or not")
count = 0
for i in alphabets:
    if i == searchLetter:
        print('The Letter "',searchLetter,'" is available and it\'s position is',count )

    else:
        print("Letter Not found")
        break

    count += 1
```

***HERE IS MY OUTPUT:***
Enter how many letters do you want to enter 3
Enter Alphabet A
Enter Alphabet B
Enter Alphabet C
alphabets that you've entered are  array('u', 'ABC')
A
B
C
enter the letter to search if its is available or notB
Not found

[image]

Also I have attached my output image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `break`, and it will find it. Here is a slightly better code. I have made changes to yours.

```
from array import *

alphabets = array('u', [])

lettersRange = int(input("Enter how many letters do you want to enter "))
for i in range(lettersRange):
    addLetter = input("Enter Alphabet ")
    alphabets.append(addLetter)

print("alphabets that you've entered are ", alphabets)

for i in range(len(alphabets)):
    print(alphabets[i])

searchLetter = input("enter the letter to search if its is available or not")
count = 0
for i in alphabets:
    if i == searchLetter:
        print('The Letter "',searchLetter,'" is available and it\'s position is',count )
    break
    count += 1

if(count==len(alphabets)):
    print("Not Found")
```

Comment: if(count==len(alphabets)):
    print("Not Found")    ////////can you please explain the ablove lines

Comment: I have edited the code. Essentially, if your element is not found, then the loop will have completed a number of iterations equal to the number of alphabets, hence count will be equal to number of alphabets. In that case, print not found

Answer (score 0):

Check the last piece of code:

```
searchLetter = input("enter the letter to search if its is available or not")
count = 0
for i in alphabets:
    if i == searchLetter:
        print('The Letter "',searchLetter,'" is available and it\'s position is',count )

    else:
        print("Letter Not found")
        break

    count += 1
```

Break it down: This code says that for each letter in the alphabet, if that letter is the searchLetter, print("xyz"). If that letter is not in the alphabet, print("Letter not found"). then break the loop. It is a good idea, but unfortunately the loop only tests the first letter, letter A. Then, if it isn't the searchLetter, it breaks the loop.I would suggest:

```
found = False
for i in alphabets:
    if i == searchLetter:
        print("xyz")
        found = True
if not found:
    print("Letter not found")
```